# Is there an argument to delete the mean header for a dataframe created after using agg and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

This is the input that I have at the moment

| Week | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.7792 |
| 1 | 0.0621 |
| 1 | 0.1412 |
| 2 | 0.6228 |
| 2 | 0.8945 |
| 3 | 0.2404 |
| 3 | 0.4243 |

And I am expecting something like this:

| Week | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3275 |
| 2 | 0.7587 |
| 3 | 0.3323 |

For this I was trying to use the following line of code:

```
use = dfQA.groupby(['Week']).agg({'Score': ['mean']}).reset_index()
```

however, this is what I get

|  | index | Week | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | mean |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.845884 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0.909470 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0.814601 |

An extra row with the word mean, I know there might be a very simple solution, but I have not been able to find it, this is what I would need to receive:

|  | index | Week | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.845884 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0.909470 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0.814601 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove mean from the list {'Score': ['mean']} ==> {'Score': 'mean'}

Comment: dfQA.groupby(['Week']).agg({'Score': 'mean'}).reset_index()

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you don't need to enclose the groupby args in `[]`. But you do want to add `drop=True` when you reset the index to get rid of the extra column.

```
import pandas as pd

dfQA = pd.DataFrame({'Week': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3},
     'Score': {0: 0.7792,
      1: 0.0621,
      2: 0.1412,
      3: 0.6228,
      4: 0.8945,
      5: 0.2404,
      6: 0.4243}})    

dfgb = dfQA.groupby('Week').agg({'Score': 'mean'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
    Score
0   0.32750
1   0.75865
2   0.33235
```